# Eliminar elemento con .remove jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Pues como dice el titulo estoy intentando eliminar elementos que añado a un div con `.append` pero no lo consigo.

**El .append**

```
$("#elPedido").append('<div class="lineasComanda">\
                         <div class="row" style="margin: 0px;">\
                            <div class="col-2 center" style="padding: 0px;">\
                               <img src="'+ resultProNormal.productNormal.foto +'" alt="" class="imgComanda">\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="col-5" style="padding: 0px;">\
                               <h2>'+ resultProNormal.productNormal.name +'</h2>\
                               <small>Familiar</small>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="col-1" style="padding: 0px;">\
                                <h5>x1</h5>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="col-2 txtRight" style="padding: 0px;">\
                                <h5>'+ resultProNormal.productNormal.precio +'€</h5>\
                            </div>\
                            <div class="col-2 center" style="padding: 0px;">\
                                <div class="deleteFila"><a class="delete"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a></div>\
                                </div>\
                            </div>\
                         </div>');
```

**La función para eliminar**

```
$("body").on("click",".deleteFila", function(){
  var indice = $(".deleteFila").index(this);
  console.log(indice);
  //carrito.splice(indice, 1);
  $(this).parent(".lineasComanda").remove();
});
```

El `console.log(indice)` si me trae el indice de forma correcta, es decir la función si esta funcionando. Si por lo contrario al `append` le quito todos el `.div row` y los `cols` dejando solo un div dentro de `lineasComanda` si que me lo elimina sin problemas.

No se como llegar a que me coja todos esos divs.

Saludos

**Edición**

Lo he solucionado así pero no se si está bien porque no llego a comprender por que así funciona.

```
$(this).closest(".lineasComanda").remove();
```

Comment: Claro, es que para que la llamada `$(this).parent(".lineasComanda")` funcionase, el div `.lineasComanda` tendría que ser su padre inmediato, y no lo es porque se interpone el `.row` entre ellos.  `$(this).closest(".lineasComanda")` te funciona porque la función `.closest()` busca al padre más cercano que cumpla con las condiciones indicadas (que no tiene por qué ser el inmediato).

Comment: Entonces es correcto @Bettylex ? por lo que dices imagino que si

Comment: Así es. `$(this).closest(".lineasComanda")` sería lo correcto. ;)

Comment: Si lo ves oportuno puedes poner una respuesta con la explicación por si le puede servir a otra persona, o no es necesario?

Comment: Claro, me parece bien si puede servir a alguien. Voy a ello.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Bettylex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dada tu estructura HTML, la llamada `$(this).parent(".lineasComanda")` no puede funcionar porque la función `.parent()` busca al padre inmediato y, en este caso, el div `.lineasComanda` no lo es, ya que el div `.row` se interpone entre ellos.

`$(this).closest(".lineasComanda")` es lo correcto en este caso, ya que la función `.closest()` busca al padre más cercano que cumpla con las condiciones indicadas, así que se salta al padre `.row` (por no cumplirlas) y logra llegar al `.lineasComanda`.